# C# CosmosDB How to get only elements in array matching a specific value

Tags: c#, jquery, mongodb

I'm using the MongoDB API on CosmosDB.
My document has the following structure inside CosmosDB:

```
{
    "_id": "Companies",
    "companies_list": [
         {
            "name":"c1",
            "host": "www.example1.com"
         },{
            "name":"c2",
            "host": "www.example2.com"
         },{
            "name":"c3",
            "host": "www.example3.com"
         },{
            "name":"c4",
            "host": "www.example1.com"
         },
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to project only elements in array which match the host condition?

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```cs
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", "Companies");
var filterOnProjection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("host", "www.example1.com");
var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.ElemMatch("companies_list", filterOnProjection);
```

Should return:

```
{
    "_id": "Companies",
    "companies_list": [
         {
            "name":"c1",
            "host": "www.example1.com"
        },{
            "name":"c4",
            "host": "www.example1.com"
         },
    ]
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Some queries just cannot be nicely written using the current version of the C# driver... Try this one:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", "Companies");
var result = collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(filter)
    .Project("{ 'companies_list': { $filter: { input: '$companies_list', cond: { $eq: [ '$$this.host', 'www.example1.com' ] } } } }")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I get a MongoCommandException with the following error message: "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '21'"

Comment: Hmm. There is no 21 in my example so what code are you running?